# Can a number have both a periodic an a non-periodic representation in a non-integer base?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, decimal-expansion

Fix an algebraic number $\beta$ and consider a complex number $\alpha$ which admits multiple [representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_base_systems) in base $\beta$. **If one representation of $\alpha$ is ultimately periodic, must every other representation of $\alpha$ be ultimately periodic**?

*Bonus question*: Does this depend on the choice of the set of digits?

*Edit*: John Bentin showed that this is false in general, even with $\beta \in \Bbb{Q}$. Is this true at least for $\beta$ algebraic integer?

*Edit 2*: This question came up when trying to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234145/what-are-the-bases-beta-such-that-a-number-with-non-periodic-expansion-can-be) problem of mine.

---

*All I know so far* is that if $\beta$ is a Pisot integer, i.e. if it is a real algebraic integer greater than $1$ with every conjugate lying in the unit circle, then $\alpha \in \Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ if and only if it has an ultimately periodic expansion (which is stronger than my question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $2=\frac23+\frac49+\cdots+(\frac23)^k+\cdots$, which is clearly periodic. Let us write, alternatively, $$2=1+\dfrac23+\dfrac{8}{27}+\dfrac{512}{19683}+\cdots,$$or$$1=\dfrac23+\dfrac{8}{27}+\dfrac{512}{19683}+\cdots=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^k}{3^k}a_k,$$ where $a_1=1,a_2=0,a_3=1,a_4=\cdots=a_{8}=0,a_{9}=1,$ and generally $a_n=1$ if $$1-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{2^k}{3^k}a_k>\dfrac{2^n}{3^n},$$ with $a_n=0$ otherwise. A proof that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac23\right)\!^ka_k=1$ is appended below. We will show that the sequence $(a_1,a_2,...)$ cannot be eventually periodic. To do this, suppose the contrary. Then there are integers $l\geqslant0$ and $m\geqslant1$ such that$$1-\left(\dfrac23+\dfrac{8}{27}+\dfrac{512}{19683}+\cdots+\dfrac{2^l}{3^l}\right)
=\dfrac{2^{l+1}}{3^{l+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\dfrac{2^{k-1}}{3^{k-1}}a_{l+k}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{mk}}{3^{mk}}$$ $$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\qquad\qquad\quad=\dfrac{2^{l+1}p}{3^l(3^m-2^m)},$$ where $p$ is an integer. Now the fraction on the LHS, in its lowest terms, has an odd numerator, while the fraction on the RHS has an even numerator: a contradiction.

**Edit:** To prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac23\right)\!^ka_k=1,$ we show by induction that $$0<1-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{2^k}{3^k}a_k<2\frac{2^n}{3^n}\quad(n=1,2,..).$$This is true for $n=1,$ since $0<1<\frac43.$ Now suppose that it has been established for $n=j,$ namely $$0<1-\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\dfrac{2^k}{3^k}a_k<2\frac{2^j}{3^j}.$$(Case 1) If $$1-\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\frac{2^k}{3^k}a_k>\frac{2^j}{3^j},$$then $a_j=1,$ and $$0<1-\sum_{k=1}^j\frac{2^k}{3^k}a_k=1-\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\dfrac{2^k}{3^k}a_k-\frac{2^j}{3^j}<2\frac{2^j}{3^j}-\frac{2^j}{3^j}=\frac{2^j}{3^j}<2\frac{2^{j+1}}{3^{j+1}}.$$(Case 2) If $$1-\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\frac{2^k}{3^k}a_k<\frac{2^j}{3^j},$$then $a_j=0,$ and $$0<1-\sum_{k=1}^j\frac{2^k}{3^k}a_k=1-\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\frac{2^k}{3^k}a_k<\frac{2^j}{3^j}<2\frac{2^{j+1}}{3^{j+1}}.$$This completes the inductive step.

Comment: Right, silly me. One last follow up question: do you know what happens if we add the hypothesis that $\beta$ is an algebraic integer?

Comment: @A.P.: Hmm ... I'll have to think about that!

Comment: If you can't figure it out I'll accept this answer anyway, since you answered my original question. It would be nice if you could explain how you thought of this example, though.

Comment: @A.P.: Just luck, really. I tried the simplest number that might have worked---and it did!

Comment: Question: How do we know this series converges to 2, rather than something smaller?  Thank you!

Comment: @HarryAltman: I have explained this in the appended edit.

Comment: OK, thank you!  So this works, then, because $2/3 \ge 1/2$; or, inverting, $3/2 \le 2$.  So I guess more generally the ceiling of your (bigger than 1) base determines how many different digits you need?

Comment: @HarryAltman: Yes: the number of digits needed is the ceiling of the base. For an arbitrary non-integral base $>1,$ I guess that there are continuum-many aperiodic representations of every real number---in particular, for those (countably many) reals that have a periodic representation in the base. Sorry, I don't know the literature on this subject and can't provide a reference.

Answer (score 2):

The following counterexample answers the supplementary question added in the edit. Choose the algebraic integer $\sqrt2$ as the base. Then we may expand $1$ in the periodic form $$1=\frac12+\frac14+\cdots+\left(\frac{0}{(\sqrt2)^{2k-1}}+\frac{1}{(\sqrt2)^{2k}}\right)+\cdots.$$But we can also express it in a more irregular expansion:$$1=\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac14+\frac1{32}+\frac1{64\sqrt2}+\cdots+\frac{a_k}{\sqrt2^k}+\cdots,$$where $a_k=1$ if $$1-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{a_j}{\sqrt2^j}>\frac1{\sqrt2^k},$$ with $a_k=0$ otherwise, for $k=1,2,\dots\,$. To show that the irregular expansion is aperiodic, assume the contrary: namely that there exist integers $l\geqslant0$ and $m\geqslant1$ satisfying $$1=\sum_{k=1}^l\frac{a_k}{\sqrt2^k}+\frac1{\sqrt2^{l+1}}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{a_{l+k}}{\sqrt2^k}\frac1{1-1/\sqrt2^{m}}.$$We may ensure that $l$ is positive by including, if necessary, the first cycle of $m$ terms of the periodic tail in the initial (pre-periodic) length-$l$ segment of the expansion. Since the terminal factor $1/(1-1/\sqrt2^{m})$ is either a positive rational number or the sum of a positive rational number and a positive rational multiple of $\sqrt2,$ the whole of the RHS of the above sum is of this form. Moreover it is not rational---because the initial segment (of length $l$) includes the first term $1/\sqrt2,$ and so the overall coefficient of $\sqrt2$ is at least $\frac12$. But the LHS is rational: a contradiction.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the argument in your last paragraph. Are you saying that the summands in the RHS are all positive elements of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and, because of that, the first term makes the whole of it irrational? Why cannot $1/\sqrt{2}$ sum to a rational number?

Comment: @A.P.: They are not just positive elements of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$: they are positive elements of the semiring $\Bbb Q_{\geqslant0}+\sqrt2\Bbb Q_{\geqslant0}.$  The RHS is the sum of a *finite* number of terms (at most $l+2m$ of them when multiplied out), each of which is a positive rational number or a positive rational multiple of $\sqrt2$. One of these terms (the first) is $\frac12\sqrt2$, and adding a *finite* (possibly zero) number of positive rational multiples of $\sqrt2$ to this first term yields a positive rational multiple of $\sqrt2$.

Comment: You may wish to have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234145/what-are-the-bases-beta-such-that-a-number-with-non-periodic-expansion-can-be) question for some easy rep... I realised that for my problem I could assume $\alpha \notin \Bbb{Q}(\beta)$, which (almost) trivializes the problem, and I would hate a bounty to go lost (as I cannot award it to myself).