# Monograph about periodic representations of numbers in non-integer bases

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, decimal-expansion

I'm looking for a monograph (book, article, lecture notes, whatever) about the representation of numbers (real or complex) in non-integer bases.

*I am especially interested in results about algebraic numbers*. For example, possible equivalent conditions to "a real number in $[0,1)$ has a periodic $\beta$-expansion iff it lies in $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$".

All I could find on my own were the relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation#Properties) and lots of results on the uniqueness of $\beta$ expansions of almost every number (for appropriate $\beta$, wrt an appropriate measure).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232794/can-a-number-have-both-a-periodic-an-a-non-periodic-representation-in-a-non-inte.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, that question is mine, too, and they both stem from the same problem.

Comment: I see. Then it would be more helpful for you to aks a specific question about this problem. Monographs are too general - in general.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Still, I am interested in getting an idea of what the state of the art is in this matter, so I think that this question is valid. I shall heed your suggestion and ask about my specific problem in another question, though.

Comment: @DietrichBurde [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234145/what-are-the-bases-beta-such-that-a-number-with-non-periodic-expansion-can-be) question explains my problem. Suggestions for a better title are welcome...

Comment: I don't know much about this topic, but I made some comments and gave some references that might be of use in this [5 July 2002 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?threadID=83218). Also, try googling ["multiplicatively independent" bases](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22multiplicatively+independent%22+bases).